# Angular 5 - Can't bind to 'inputs' since it isn't a known property of 'ngu-carousel'

Tags: angular

I try to use ngu-carousel but I have error below:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'inputs' since it
>   isn't a known property of 'ngu-carousel'.
>   1. If 'ngu-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'inputs' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'ngu-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("][inputs]="carouselOne">

Any idea?

Comment: Did you import the `ngu-carousel` module in your `@NgModele`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I import it in home.component.ts too, to bind value of inputs

Comment: may be this link would be useful:- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngu/carousel